# New to JavaFX and still trying to figure out a shrinking bullseye Application

Tags: java, animation, javafx

So far everything in my application is working.

Function:
The bullseye will appear, then once the animate me button is clicked, the first three circles inside the bullseye will shrink. Then new circles will be created in alternating colors.

Problem:
Everything is working thus far except for the pause and play functions I'm trying to implement. I'm planning on making the bullseye stop when the user hits the stop button in the middle, yet pick up wherever it was left off with no hiccups, no skipped circles, etc. Like i said, I'm fairly new to this so I'm just wondering if the problem was that I didn't use the Timeline class in order to try and manage how it was paused and played? Or is the problem with the last two event handlers (btn.setOnMousedPressed and btn.setOnMouseReleased) and the for loops not reaching a certain index?

Thanks for the help!

```
        public class BullsEye extends Application 
{
    Circle[] cir = new Circle[100];
    Button btn = new Button("Animate me!");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        root.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");      

        cir[0] = new Circle(400, 250, 200);
        cir[0].setFill(Color.RED);
        cir[0].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        cir[1] = new Circle(315, 165, 115);
        cir[1].setFill(Color.WHITE);
        cir[1].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        cir[2] = new Circle(230, 80, 30);
        cir[2].setFill(Color.RED);
        cir[2].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        root.getChildren().addAll(cir[0], cir[1], cir[2]);      
        root.getChildren().add(btn);      

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        btn.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            animation();
            btn.setText("Press to Stop");
        });
    }

    public void animation()
    {
        ScaleTransition[] st = new ScaleTransition[100];

        st[0]= new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), cir[0]);
        st[0].setToX(0.0f);
        st[0].setToY(0.0f);
        st[0].play();

        st[1] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(5.5), cir[1]);
        st[1].setToX(0.0f);
        st[1].setToY(0.0f);
        st[1].play();

        st[2] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(4), cir[2]);
        st[2].setToX(0.0f);
        st[2].setToY(0.0f);
        st[2].play();

       // int delayInc = 1;
        int delay = 1;


        for(int i = 3; i<st.length; i++)
        {     
            if(i % 2 == 1)
            {
                cir[i] = new Circle(400,250,200);
                cir[i].setFill(Color.WHITE);
                cir[i].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");
                root.getChildren().add(cir[i]);
                cir[i].toBack();

                st[i] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), cir[i]);
                st[i].setDelay(Duration.seconds(delay));

                delay++;
                st[i].setToX(0.0f);
                st[i].setToY(0.0f);
                st[i].play();
            }

            else if(i%2==0)
            {
                cir[i] = new Circle(400, 250, 200);
                cir[i].setFill(Color.RED);
                cir[i].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");
                root.getChildren().add(cir[i]);
                cir[i].toBack();

                st[i] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), cir[i]);
                //st[i].setDuration(Duration.seconds(7));
                //st[i].setNode(cir[i]);
                st[i].setDelay(Duration.seconds(delay));
                delay++;
                st[i].setToX(0.0f);
                st[i].setToY(0.0f);
                st[i].play();
            }
        }

        btn.setOnMousePressed(event ->
        {
            for(int x = 0; x<st.length;x++)
            st[x].pause();

            btn.setText("Release to Resume");
        });    

        btn.setOnMouseReleased(event -> 
        {
            for(int y = 0; y<st.length;y++)
            st[y].play();
        });
    }  
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why there are so many circles. Only about 6 or 7 are visible. You surely need to just create, say, 6 circles. Give each one a scale transition with `cycleCount` set to `INDEFINITE`. Add all the scale transitions to a `ParallelTransition`, and then you should be able to just pause and play the `ParallelTransition`.

Comment: You could also just create a single circle and use a [radial gradient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typepaint) as the fill. Then in the animation, just change the stops for the gradient. The details of that might be a little tricky, but it would be efficient.